# How to make subprocess be called after another command in Python?

Tags: python, subprocess

I want to write Python script. I am somekind new to it. In that script I want to run another C program, which gives many numbers in output. Smth like:

```
1   1   0.000000    0.000172    0.075010    0.937330    33.743876
```

I want to run this program multiple times with other parameters and to collect all outputs in one file. After that I plan to use `pandas` to sort data and make some plots, but it is not important now. I wrote the following code:

```
import subprocess

f = open("ax-rrff.dat", "w")
f.write("seed\tN\tT\tDRA\tD\tActive\tAvF\n")

p = subprocess.call(['gcc', 'ax-rrff.c', '-lm','-lgsl','-lgslcblas'])

for seed in range(1,2+1):
    for N in range(1,2+1):
        p = subprocess.call(['a.exe',str(seed),'1',str(N),'1000','0','0'], stdout=f)

f.close()
```

(small numbers just to show you). I expect my `ax-rrff.dat` to be

```
seed    N   T   DRA D   Active  AvF
1   1   0.000000    0.000172    0.075010    0.937330    33.743876
1   2   0.000000    0.003598    0.021690    1.564677    14.032332
2   1   0.000000    0.000172    0.062262    0.925817    33.329404
2   2   0.000000    0.002790    0.014749    1.423670    16.689964
```

However, scheduler of compiler thinks that it would be cool to make output in this way:

```
1   1   0.000000    0.000172    0.075010    0.937330    33.743876
1   2   0.000000    0.003598    0.021690    1.564677    14.032332
2   1   0.000000    0.000172    0.062262    0.925817    33.329404
2   2   0.000000    0.002790    0.014749    1.423670    16.689964
seed    N   T   DRA D   Active  AvF
```

The question. How can I force sub-processes to run after  `f.write("seed\tN\tT\tDRA\tD\tActive\tAvF\n")`?

Comment: You can first flush the output to the file before calling the subprocess.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice

 `f = open("ax-rrff.dat", "w")

f.write("seed\tN\tT\tDRA\tD\tActive\tAvF\n")

f.close()

f =  open("ax-rrff1.dat", "a")`

works

Comment: Or you can flush, rather than close.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Oh, thanks! I forgot about `f.flush()` command. Yes. It cooler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `write()` places output in a buffer and only periodically flushes the buffer to disk. Since you have multiple processes writing to the file, they can potentially each flush their own buffer before the parent process does. To force the output, just call `f.flsuh()` before starting any subprocesses.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I am.on the phone so can't test my answer but I guess your expected output could be achieved like this:

```
import subprocess 
f = open("ax-rrff.dat", "a")
f.write("seed\tN\tT\tDRA\tD\tActive\tAvF\n")

p = subprocess.call(['gcc', 'ax-rrff.c', '-lm','-lgsl','-lgslcblas']) 

for seed in range(1,2+1): 
    for N in range(1,2+1): 
        newcall = subprocess.Popen(['a.exe',str(seed),'1',str(N),'1000','0','0'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE) 
        newcall.wait()
        output, errors = newcall.communicate()
        f.write(output.decode())

f.close()
```

This would leave one thing unclear though.. since you are declaring `p` outside the for-loop and then again once inside it.. This leads me to believe you are willing to use the first declaration as input for the second one.. however, what you are doing is simply making a new declaration and thereby overwriting the first one. So you are changing what `p` is, not using/executing it in any way..

Further explanation:

I changed `open(file, 'w')` to `open(file, 'a')`, this means the file will be `append` mode rather then `write` mode. This allows you to write as often as you'd like to it and it will add each line in the order it is written to the file from.within your python script.

If you'd still like to use the first declaration of `p` as input for the second declaration see if you can do so by extending the command line command you insert into subprocess in the for loop.

Comment: 1. subprocess has `Popen` attribute, not `popen`
2. I will get what I want with your code if I place `f.write("seed\tN\tT\tDRA\tD\tActive\tAvF\n")` just after `f = open("ax-rrff.dat", "a")`

Comment: You could place f.write() at the top but that would leave your descriptive line at the top.. I thought you wanted it at the bottom of the file?

Comment: no! I want it at the top of the file. here is the question. My compiler for some unknown reasons (for me) prints it at the bottom

Comment: @Dida It's your code that prints at the bottom, not the compiler.